# Reference for Tate vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

... aka locally linear compact vector spaces. The one reference I know is http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Nov3-10(CentExt).pdf. Does anyone know another good reference?

Comment: How about Tate's original article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Beilinson, Drinfeld.  *Chiral Algebras* section 2.7 (I think)
2. Beilinson, Feigin, Mazur.  *Notes on Conformal Field Theory (Incomplete)* available on Mazur's web page.

Also: Tate, *Residues of differentials on curves*